# Indicating degree with 比 and 不如

Tags: grammar

When using 比, you are able to add a classifying degree. For example,
一个苹果比一个香蕉贵*一块元*。

Can you do the same with 不如?

一个香蕉不如一个苹果贵*一块元*
??

Comment: 一个香蕉比一个苹果便宜一块钱 (Note: not 一块元，but 一块钱)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can you do the same with 不如?*

No, you can't. 不如 means "not as"

> *"一根香蕉不如一个苹果贵(一元)"*
>
> *"A banana is not as expensive as an apple (by a dollar)"*
>
> It is ungrammatical in either Chinese or English.
>
> "A banana is not as expensive as an apple" doesn't matter it is ten cents less or one dollar less

It has to be "一根香蕉不如一个苹果贵" (A banana is not as expensive as an apple)

When we use [(A) not as (adj) as(B)]. e.g. [(a duck) is not as (heavy) as (a goose)], we cannot make it specific, because a goose can be heavier than a duck by wide range of degree

you cannot put a specific amount/number after "鴨不如鵝重" and say ""鴨不如鵝重30％" ; you can only say "鵝一般來說比鴨重30％" (a goose in general is 30% heavier than a duck)